# Jquery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I'd like to change the Default `altFormat`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
$("#myFav").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
$("#myFav").datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
```

I thought altFormat would work just the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This changes the dateformat in my application:

```
$("#startdate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried what the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-altFormat) says:

```
$('.selector').datepicker({ altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

or

```
$('.selector').datepicker('option', 'altFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
```

For both the dateFormat and the altFormat:

```
$('.selector').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

Answer (score 0):

dateFormat set the date of the input that datepicker was called on, use altFormat and altField  if you want to set the value of a seperate field (a hidden field that actually get sent to database, or is shared somehow by the application)

This code worked for me:

[IN HTML]

`<label for="display_date">Display/Start Date</label><br />`

`<input type="text" class="dateStart" name="display_date" value="" /><br />`

`<label for="display_date_end">End Date</label><br />`

`<input type="text" class="dateEnd" name="display_date_end" value="" /><br />`

[IN JAVASCRIPT INCLUDE]

`// set the datePicker on the start and end fields`

`$('input.dateStart').datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd", changeYear: true});`

`$('input.dateEnd').datepicker({`

`dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",`

`changeYear: true,`

`beforeShow: function(){`

`var value = $(this).siblings('.dateStart').val();`

`$(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', value);`

`}`

`});`

bo huttinger